# Why does Powershell v2 Copy-Item seem to be copying a directory instead of individual items?

Tags: copy, powershell-2.0

I'm a Powershell novice, and am running what I consider to be a fairly simple script to copy files from the network to my local machine.

```
$htmPath = "\\ServerPath\foo\WebHelp\"
$dstPath = "C:\LocalPath\foo\WebHelp\"
Copy-Item $htmPath $dstPath -recurse -force
```

However, all my data lands in `C:\LocalPath\foo\WebHelp\Webhelp\`; it appears that my copy is creating a new instance of the `WebHelp` directory instead of copying the contents. Is that normal? Why is it happeneing? How do I need to modify my script to ONLY copy the contents of a folder, and not the folder name?

For instance, if I only want to copy `files` NOT `\WebHelp\files` from `\\serverpath\foo\WebHelp\files`. I have been unsuccessful with various iterations of adding or deleting an ending `\` and using `copy` instead of `copy-item`. What is the proper syntax to eliminate the parent folder name from appending to the path during a copy?

Comment: not sure per powershell... but in *NIX commands  sometimes the ending slash makes a difference.  Have you tried "...foo\webhelp" ?

Comment: I did, actually...same results with or without the final \.

Answer (score 1):

First: switch `-WhatIf` can display your info for testing purposes about copying.

Second: There is no need to do file per file when you copying directory. if you want to go file per file, you can use `$htmPath\*` to get child items. Or `Get-ChildItem`

You can se your dstPath to `"C:\LocalPath\foo\"`

Comment: I do not want to go file by file, I just want to copy the FILES in the directory, NOT the directory. Is there a way to suppress that? I have been unsucessful.

Answer (score 0):

there are various options you can use to get different results when copying from one folder to another.

```
$htmPath = "\\ServerPath\foo\WebHelp\"
$dstPath = "C:\LocalPath\foo\WebHelp\"
Copy-Item $htmPath $dstPath -recurse -force
```

Your code is explicitly selecting the htm path folder and its files/subfolders to copy to the destination path.

```
Copy-Item $htmPath\* $dstPath -recurse -force
```

Changing your from path to end in `\*` will get, what I believe is, your desired result of copying the htm path files and subfolders to the destination path.

If you only want the files, and not the subfolders, remove `-recurse`.

Read more about copying from one location to another [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/04/19/use-powershell-to-copy-files-and-folders-to-a-new-location.aspx). Copy-Item command information [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156818.aspx).